# Issue with launchMode Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, launchmode

I am implementing a custom launcher. I have two activity : Activity A with launchMode : singleInstance or singleTask, and Activity B.

Activity A is main screen. There are 2 case :

- If i set Activity A launchMode : singleTask, I call Activity B from Activity A (That's fine). In Activity B, if i press Home key to back main screen, then screen is empty(no any thing...).
- If i set Activity A launchMode :  singleInstance, I call Activity B from Activity A, then it shows a blank screen, after go to Activity B(in this case , I press Home key to bac main screen, it works fine).

So, how to resolve this? I want : Call Activity B from Activity A, then it go to Activity B directly, and when I press Home key, it go back to main screen (Activity A).

Answer (score 1):

in Activity B you can use following code with back button

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        Intent a = new Intent(this,A.class);
        a.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(a);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

if you wants to work with home key than override Home key with following code

```
 @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
       if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)
        {
          //yours code action
return true;
        }
       if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
       {
           //yours code action
return true;
       }
      return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

please you may try with this as well

```
@Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {

        if ( (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) && isLock) {
            //yours code
            return true;
        }
        else
            return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In this case, you set SingleTask or SingleInstance ? Morever, I only get problem with Home key. I added onKeyDown in Activity B with keyCode = KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME, but this problem is not still working.

Comment: please write code like this...@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) {
       //yours code
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

Comment: I updated your code, but it doesn't run into OnKeyDown with KEYCODE_HOME. I don't understand. if i switch to case 2 (singleInstance). How to fix it?

Comment: did you add <meta-data android:name="android.dock_home" android:value="true" /> line in yours manifest

Comment: i updated the answer please use    @Override
        public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    
            if ( (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) && isLock) {
                //yours code
                return true;
            }
            else
                return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
        }

Answer (score 0):

try this one...
remove launchmode attribute from manifest and then,call Activity B from Activity A
using finish() method as follows:

```
finish();
            Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ActivityB.class);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: As I ask above. There are 2 case : 
If i set Activity A launchMode : singleTask/singleTast/standard, I call Activity B from Activity A (That's fine). In Activity B, if i press Home key to back main screen, then screen is empty(no any thing...). How to fix it?


If i set Activity A launchMode : singleInstance, I call Activity B from Activity A, then it shows a blank screen (How to fix it), after go to Activity B(in this case , i press Home key to back main screen, it works fine).